# Not detecting beacons if I kill the app from the Task Manager

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon, beacon

I'm using Altbeacon to detect iBeacons.

If the app is in foreground or if the app is in background through the "home" button works fine. In both cases works perfectly.

But, when I try to detect beacons after killing the app through the Task Manager, there isn't any way to detect any beacon. I'm going crazy.

I'm using the last version of Altbeacon, and this is my code (Application class):

```
public void startBeaconScan() {

        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
        setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));  //iBeacon layout

        beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(500);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(500);
        beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(500);
        beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(500);

        beaconManager.setRegionStatePeristenceEnabled(false);
        beaconManager.bind(this);

        region = new Region("myMonitoringUniqueId", Identifier.parse("2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6"), null, null);
        new RegionBootstrap(this, region);
    }
```

I've read a lot of posts but I've not found any solution yet.

Smartphones used to test: Xiaomi Redmi Note 2, Samsung Galaxy S5

---------------- UPDATE ------------------------

Code for the RegionBootstrap callbacks:

```
@Override
    public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int arg0, Region arg1) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Got a didDetermineStateForRegion call: " + arg1.getId1());
    }

    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Got a didEnterRegion call: " + arg0.getId1());
    }

    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region arg0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Got a didExitRegion call: " + arg0.getBluetoothAddress());
    }
```

For each one I've the default logs, and none of them is shown after the app is killed.

Comment: after killing the app through the Task Manager, the app no longer run's in the device. Then how can you expect it to run?

Comment: After killing the app, if I understood correctly, the app should be detecting beacons because the RegionBootstrap (http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/resume-after-terminate.html)

Comment: The library is designed to restart scanning in the background within 5 minutes of killing the app.  Do you wait 5 minutes?  Can you post your code that sets up a RegionBootstrap and shows it's callbacks?

Comment: Yes, I have waited up to 15 minutes. I will update the question with the callbakcs. Thanks @davidgyoung

Comment: What calls the startBeaconScan method?  If you add a debug line there, do you see it within 5 minutes of killing the app?

Comment: The startBeaconScan method is called by the MainActivity's onCreate() method. I'm not seeing any log after 5 minutes of killing the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to auto launch you app to scan for beacons after being killed, the RegionBootstrap must be configured in the onCreate method of a custom Application class not an Activity.

See here for more info: http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/background_launching.html

Comment: Wow! it's true! Now seems that is working. After killing the app, the smartphone is detecting beacons, but there's a new problem... After a minute more or less, the app stops scanning beacons. I have waited about 10 minutes, and it doesn't scan again. Any idea?

Comment: Sounds like a different issue.  Please create a new question showing your setup code and explaining how you know it stopped scanning.  Any logs would be helpful.

Comment: Ok, I will prepare a new post with logs =)
A little question: when I boot the smartphone, the beacon detection service does not start automatically ... Is this behavior normal? I thought it started automatically when the boot is completed.

Comment: david, a little question. If I'm inside a beacon region a lot of time, is a normal behaviour that the app stops scanning new beacons?